# yet another: c++ - invalid conversion from 'const type*' to 'type*'

Tags: c++

As simple as this: I want to specify that a function would not change its pointer argument. How to?

```
class A {
private:
  int *p;
public:
  void foo (const int *q) {
    p = q;
  }
};

A a;
int b = 3;
int *c = &b;
a.foo(c);
```

Still not working, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're accepting a `const int*` argument and trying to save it in a non-`const` variable. The error message is trying to explain this to you, so take a moment to read it more carefully.

Comment: Yes you say that the function *itself* will not modify what `q` is pointing to. But then you save it in an non-constant pointer so *other* member functions could modify the data.

Comment: `A = a;` What is this? Your attention to detail is low.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am just wanting to say that the function is not going to modify q.

Comment: @user180574: First of all you mean `b` not `q`; again, attention to detail. Secondly, "stripping away `const` so that other code can modify it" counts as "will modify". Think of it this way: `foo` said "I don't want a licence to modify `b`" ... so it can't give such a licence to anybody else, either.

Comment: I'm sure your C++ book explains this...

Comment: "Still not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have clarified that you did not *intend* to add constness to the pointee, but instead to the pointer (and this can of course be safely dropped when copying the pointer). The error message is a good indication that you failed in that goal.

The type to do that is:

```
int* const
```

Remember, `const` applies directly to the left (unless there's nothing there, in which case it applies directly to the right).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in 'foo()' a const pointer, this means that you are telling compiler that you don't want anyone to change the data ponted by the pointer. Therefore, converting a const pointer to a non-const pointer makes no-sense. However, if you really want to do so 'just for fun' then you can workaround this by 'memcpy'.

Comment: `memcpy` would be a strange approach. `const_cast` surely